# Add footprint to PCB Library in Altium

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, library

I inherited a project from an engineer who just left our company. In his  (Altium) PCB Layout, there's a footprint on the board for a 2 pin connector, but it's not in the library. I need to edit the footprint, and I can't figure out how to add it to the library so that I can edit it... Let alone to have in the pcb library... Tried the "Design -> Make PCB Library" option, it grabbed every part but this one.... Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually a component footprint and not just a collection of free primitives on the board?

Comment: That's the thing... it shows up as a component. 3D rendering and all.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround that I always use is to select the component in the PCB, press CTRL+C, Define the selection Origin, open the target library with a new blank component, and the press CTRL+V, and drop it where you want and save.

Remember to make sure that the origin is where you want it.